# Javascript Remove Style-Attribute with no ID given

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i delete the whole style from

```
<div class="style1 style2" style="width:200px; color:red"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="style1 style2"></div>
```

Without having an ID in the div and no way to add one?
Without ID i cant use getElementById...

Can you help?

Comment: [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is your friend.

Comment: Try `document.querySelector('.style1').setAttribute('style', '');`

Comment: How you access that specific element would depend on your higher level use case. Any element with `style` in page, only one specific element with that class etc. Provide more specific details and a [mcve]. ALso take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `querySelectorAll` to query your expected elements and then use `removeAttribute` to remove style attribute

```js
function removeStyle() {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll("div.style1.style2");
  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.removeAttribute('style')
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="style1 style2" style="width:200px; color:red">TEST</div>
<button onclick="removeStyle()">Remove Style</button>
```

Comment: great support !